# How to obfuscate the src attribute of an audio tag

Tags: javascript, java, audio, encryption

I am currently building a web application where I would be playing a user uploaded files, where the user uploaded files can be only streamed. The Problem is how would I hide or obfuscate the audio tag src attribute but at the same time the audio file can still be streamed/played and retrieved from  the database?

The main purpose of this is that I want to source of the audio file.

Answer (score 3):

There's no sensible way to accomplish what you say you want to do. If the  element can find the file, so can any user with debugging tools enabled in their browser. What's the purpose you're trying to serve by obscuring the URL to the source?

Comment: I generally want my audio file to be secured so that no one could access it from my server

Comment: If users can play the audio, then they can **by definition** access it. You are trying to draw a distinction where none exists.

Comment: Seriously, user962206 - you need to change your question to explain what you're *actually* trying to accomplish, at a high level. Asking "how can I obscure the src used by an <audio> element" isn't going to get useful answers. You can't do that. So tell us what the high-level goal is, and maybe you can get some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

- maybe you should use the web Audio API
  [GETTING STARTED WITH THE AUDIOCONTEXT](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/)

  OR
- use a server-side script (php) to load only in some circumstance
  for example you can make your website save a cookie in the user's browser
  and when you want to load the files <s>pass it value on the link</s>*

*: i forgot that cookies are sent with the request to the server (in php: use $_COOKIE super global )

Comment: care to explain more on your answer?

Comment: you can make your server set cookie on the user's browser and refer to your audio file with a php file(a loader) that will load them with specific id the role of the cookie is to protect from the users copying the paths to your files and disable cross domain use of your files because the loader needs the cookie to load files and those can only be acceded by the pages in your website's domain

Comment: I am using java for my web-application as for my server I am using   Tomcat

Comment: sorry i don't have much experience on that

Comment: @younessbelfkih, maybe you should edit your answer to include an explanation on how the web Audio API would help the OP and how to use it. Perhaps you could include code (or pseudo-code) for your server-side script suggestion. Right now, your suggestion have potential but are not clearly helpful. A few additions could make this a good answer.

Comment: The Web Audio API is concerned with client-side playback controlled by JavaScript, not DRM or server-side concerns.

Comment: You could possibly build a DRM-like system on top of Web Audio, by downloading the audio data via an authenticated XMR mechanism, and playing the audio data in Javascript. That's not really "streaming", though...